# IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: my_films.title_id

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert information into my table. But I got this problem:

```
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: my_films.title_id.
```

I can't understand why, because I don't have id, which repeat. Can you help me?

My code:

```py
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE my_films (
title_id INT, 
title TEXT, 
premiered INT,
rating REAL,
PRIMARY KEY (title_id))""")

con.commit()

films = [(1, 'Birds of Prey', 2020, 9),
    (2, 'The Avengers', 2012, 10),
    (3, 'Love Rosie', 2014, 7,6),
    (4, 'Me Before You', 2016, 7,2)]
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO my_films VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", films)
con.commit()
```

Comment: 1) what happens if you run cur.execute(...) 4 times instead of 1 executemany? 2) what is returned if you run cur.execute('select * from my_films') right before executemany?